# Rails redirect_to not working, redirecting to show instead of custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, redirecttoaction

So I have a ChatsController, and from my index action, I'm trying to redirect to a custom action, "decide":

```
def index
  @chat = Chat.customfind(params[:search])
  if(@chat.is_a?(Array))
    session[:chats] = @chat
    redirect_to :action => 'decide'
  else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @chat if !@chat.nil? }
  end
end

def decide
  @chats = session[:chats]
  @choice = Chat.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to @choice if !@choice.nil?
end
```

..where @choice is going to be decided by the params of the form on the decide page. But for some reason, instead of redirecting to decide, Rails redirects to show:

```
Started GET "/chats/decide" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-14 17:13:36 -0400
  Processing by ChatsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"decide"}
  ..............
```

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

**Edit:**
I'm assuming this is what you want... the relevant parts of my routes.rb:

```
match "chats/decide" => "chats#decide"

resources :chats do
  member do
    post 'send_message'
  end
end

get "chats/logout"
```

..yeah it's a bit of a hodgepodge :/

Comment: show your routes.rb file

Comment: Are you trying to get `/chats/decide/:id` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to achieve the following:

- Find all chats matching a given search string
- If 1 chat is found, redirect to it
- If 2+ chats are found, redirect to `/chats/decide` so the user can pick one

I would implement this as follows:

1) Update **routes.rb** as follows:

```
resources :chats do
  member do
    post :send_message
  end

  collection do
    get :decide # Produces the '/chats/decide/' route
  end
end
```

2) Change your **chats#decide** action to this:

```
def decide
  @chats = session[:chats]
end
```

3) When you list the available chats in your **decide.html.erb** file, link them directly to the appropriate `show` link.

4) Be explicit about your redirect in **chats#index**:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'chats', :action => 'decide'
```

Your **chats#decide** action should not respond differently based on whether it's receiving an `id` or not. You can link directly to the specific chats in that view.

Comment: So why does "collection do" work? As opposed to "member do" or just something like get "chats/actionname"

Comment: `collection` expects to list a collection of objects, and thus provides the route `/chats/decide`. `member` expects to list **a single object**, and thus provides the route `/chats/:chat_id/decide`.